# Spotify web API results "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

I am trying to get playlists/albums/songs with the Spotify web API. I am able to output to the console these things but if I want to get just the name I get `undefined`

I am trying to retrieve information by using 
 return data.body.tracks.name

this does not work but I can use

```
searchSpotify(req, res) {
spotifyApi.searchTracks(req.body.search).then(
  function(data) {
    // var testPage = data.body.tracks.items;
    console.log('Search by user input', data.body.tracks.items);
    res.redirect("/search");
  },
  function(err) {
    console.error(err);
    }
  );
},
```

[image: Returned Data]

this returns some information and as you can see, it also returns a name, how can I access that name to be the only thing I return in my query?

Comment: is the data in JSON format? if so try console.log(json.stringify(data.body.tracks.items))

Comment: Your image says the server is giving you a 401 response error, which means you aren't authenticated. Have you requested your API key to use it? It is not a public API.

Comment: Hi, yes the data is in JSON format, I tried your advice and it returns an illegible mess on some values and again "undefined" on others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.body.tracks.items` returns an array and `name` is nested inside `array` then inside`album` object so you have to dive deeper like this

```
let name = data.body.tracks.items[0].album.name
```

If you have multiple `Items` you might have to loop over it, in order to get every name

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `items` is an array of objects, each of which has a `name` field.

Try this:

```
searchSpotify(req, res) {
spotifyApi.searchTracks(req.body.search).then(
  function(data) {
    // var testPage = data.body.tracks.items;
    console.log('Search by user input', data.body.tracks.items);
    const items = data.body.tracks.items
    const names = items.forEach(item => console.log(item.name))
    res.redirect("/search");
  },
  function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
);
```

You should see it print each item's `name` on a new line.